# What is equivalent to VB.NET's Length keyword in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I wrote VB.NET code like this:

```vb
d = Data.IndexOf("</a>", ("target='_top' class='ab1'>").Length() + s).
```

I want to write this in C#. When I wrote the above code in C#, it said there was an error with the Length keyword. How do I write the above code in C#?

Comment: In C#, `Length` is a property.

Comment: @Jack: It's actually a property in VB too, it's just that VB lets you use properties and parameterless methods the same way; with or without parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra set of parentheses:

```
 d = Data.IndexOf("</a>", "target='_top' class='ab1'>".Length + s)
```

Try that

Answer (score 6):

`Length` is not a keyword in C# - it is either a property or an extension method on the object (like a string) that you are trying to manipulate.

So if it is a string you are using this will work:

```
myString.Length
```

(notice how the brackets are missing because it is a property).

Answer (score 1):

Check this link out:

In it, you can easliy switch between C# to a VB good, to help you migrate:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx#Y242